# Using WTForms, how can I have a field be a hidden select but show up as 2 checkboxes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, flask-wtforms, wtforms

I want to have a list of these fields, where the options are simple: for each field either it's not present, present, or critical.

But I don't want it to show up as a dropdown. I would like to have a checkbox to indicate present or not present, and then if present is selected, another checkbox (not necessarily a checkbox, could be an image you click) to toggle between critical or not critical.

I was thinking I could have a custom Field, with a widget that renders an hidden dropdown with the options: not present, present and critical. And have 2 checkboxes with no name atribute (so they won't submit?).

But I would have to have javascript to control the hidden dropdown accordingly to the other checkboxes right?
Can i embed JS into the widget? Or maybe into the form? (since many fields will be this type of field). Or do i have to have the JS separately?

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I think the better way to do this is to have a JS fils separtely. Cause a Custom field is complex and take much time than a little script. But if you won't touch JS, you can do [macro](https://github.com/datouch/jinja-form-helper) in jinja 2. Is complex too use but it work well to personalize your render field.